# detect if element has been touched during touchmove

Tags: jquery

I have a a div element within which I have other divs which are abolute positioned within that parent element at different positions. I want to detect whether a user has touched a specific element whilst touchmoving over the parent element. Is there a way this can be done?

```
<div class="area">
   <div class="point1"></div>
   <div class="point2"></div>
   <div class="point3"></div>
   <div class="point4"></div>
</div>

$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Say for example while they are toucmoving over `.area` and the touch `.point1` I want something to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you like to trigger the touchmove of .point1 , you can easily put the code below:

```
$('.point1').on('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Same thing with the other div : .point2, .point3 ....etc

Comment: doesn't work, it only detects if you start the touch on .point1 and then move on it, it doesn't detect say if you started touchmove on the parent then touch over .point1

Comment: well, if it doesn't work, try this code:
`$('.area').on('touchmove', '.point1', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`..it should work because the div .point1 is a child of the div .area